# Converting list of milliseconds with NaN values to date in python

Tags: python, dataframe, date, datetime, milliseconds

I am trying to convert millisecond to date using python: by I have a list of millisecond to convert. however, some of them are `NaN`. Hence, I am using `np.isna` to check if the value is `NaN` or not. So i am using the following code:

```
np.where(pd.isna(df['createdTime'])==False,df['createdTime'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(x)/1000.).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),'NaN'))
```

But this is still giving me the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid value NaN (not a number)
```

Can someone please help me with this? How do I convert millisecond to date by skipping the `NaN`s?

Comment: Can you give your entire code? Difficult to debug with a single line.

Comment: at least the full traceback .... and tell us what the actual thing you are trying to do is ... this is likely not quite the right approach to it whatever it is ... (its probably close)

Comment: in principle, you should look for an option that utilizes `pd.to_datetime` and avoids `apply` (looping...), for example `pd.to_datetime([1600670617376.507, 1600670617376.507, np.nan], unit='ms')` works fine with NaN.